# How can I return from a method more than one variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This method returns only the process filename:

```
public static string GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    return proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString();
}
```

But I want to return also the process name:

```
proc.ProcessName;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create and return an object describing your result:

```
public class ProcessInfo
{
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

public ProcessInfo GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);

    return new ProcessInfo 
    {
        FileName = proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString(),
        ProcessName = proc.ProcessName
    }
 }
```

Or (I personally like this less), a `Tuple<string, string>`:

```
public Tuple<string, string> GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);

    return Tuple.Create(proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString(),
                        proc.ProcessName);
}
```

Comment: The Tuple approach is great during early development, but I agree it should be refactored to an explicit class when working.

Comment: @DavidArno I hate when tuples are (currently) used in C#. I hope they get better support in C# 7.0. Currently they are utterly unreadable and make the code look like crap.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you have four options (in preference order)

- Return `proc.MainModule` directly and extract necessary information from caller.

```
public static ProcessModule GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    return proc.MainModule;
}
```

- Create a class containing both values and return that

```
public class ProcessInformation
{
    public string FileName;
    public string ProcessName;
}

public static ProcessInformation GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    var pi = new ProcessInformation 
    {  
        proc.MainModule.FileName,
        proc.MainModule.ProcessName
    }
    return pi;
}
```

- Return a tuple from method `Tuple<string, string>`

```
public static Tuple<string, string> GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    return return Tuple.Create(proc.MainModule.FileName,proc.MainModule.ProcessName);
}
```

- Create 2 `out` parameters on your method (I never seen two out parameters implemented and I discourage this since definitively smells, but it's an option C# provides)

```
string GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd, out fileName, out processName)
```

Comment: `out` params.. that's so 2002 ;P

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: yeah. it's an ugly option but language allows to do that. I would never do it but just mention it to cover all options

Answer (score 3):

Since both are `string`, how about return a `Tuple<string, string>` instead?

```
public static Tuple<string, string> GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    Tuple<string, string> t = new Tuple<string, string>
    (
         proc.MainModule.FileName,
         proc.ProcessName
    );
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Last option would be using out-params:

```
public voidstring GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd, out string fileName, out string processName{
    uint pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    fileName = proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString();
    processName = proc.ProcessName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change the return type to `Process`:

```
    public static Process GetProcessInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        uint pid = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
        return Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
     }
```

and then get the data you need from the returned object:

```
var proc = GetProcessInfo(hwnd);
var processName = proc.ProcessName;
var moduleFileName = proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString();
```